# Partial Aggregate Initialization and Non-static Data Member Initializer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
struct Point {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 10;
};

Point p = {1,};
p.x == 1;  // true
p.y == 10; // is this true?
```

According to the standard missing elements in initializer list are value initialized, so `y` should be `int()` or `0`, but it doesn't seem to say what happen in the situation of Non-static Data Member Initializer.

Edit: According to the answer, apparently this is invalid c++11, I would like to know the situation in c++1y.

Comment: I'm guessing you are talking about the new feature of *C++1y*? just making sure before I go in and tag the question.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile with g++4.9 (even with -std=c++14), but compiles with clang++ (only with the flag -std=c++1y). Anyway I get that `p.y==10` is `true`

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp: NSDMIs were introduced in C++11.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm talking about the [relaxation of aggregate initialization](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3653.html) in *C++14*.

Comment: link is broken @FilipRoséen-refp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### C++98, C++03

Non-static data member initialisers (NSDMIs) do not exist; the question is inapplicable.

---

#### C++11

Well, first of all, this initialisation is invalid because your type is not an aggregate:

> `[C++11: 8.5.1/1]:` **An aggregate is** an array or **a class** (Clause 9) **with** user-provided constructors (12.1), **no *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members** (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11),
>   no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

So, aggregate initialisation can't be performed here; a constructor taking an `std::initializer_list` would be your only way to use that initialisation syntax (`[C++11: 8.5.4/3]`), but you don't have one of those either.

Consequently, the entire premise of the question is flawed: it is not possible to get yourself into this state.

---

#### C++1y

In the upcoming version of the standard, the definition of aggregates has been relaxed to allow your type to be deemed an *aggregate* (as long as both of those members stay `public`!):

> `[n3936: 8.5.1/1]` **An aggregate is** an array or **a class** (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), **no private or protected non-static data members** (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

Following on from this, there's a rule that guarantees the result you're looking for:

> `[n3936: 8.5.1/7]`: If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from its *brace-or-equal-initializer* or, if there is no *brace-or-equal-initializer*,
>   from an empty initializer list (8.5.4). *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> struct S { int a; const char* b; int c; int d = b[a]; };
> S ss = { 1, "asdf" };
> ```
>
> initializes `ss.a` with `1`, `ss.b` with `"asdf"`, `ss.c` with the value of an expression of the form `int{}` (that is, `0`), and `ss.d` with the value of `ss.b[ss.a]` (that is, `’s’`), and in
>
> ```
> struct X { int i, j, k = 42; };
> X a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
> X b[2] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
> ```
>
> `a` and `b` have the same value *—end example ]*

Comment: Thanks, glad to see c++1y is making thing easier for me.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out, but VS 2015 does *not* support this feature, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#cpp14table

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*(Answer valid in C++1y, **only**!)*</sup>

According to paragraph #7 of section "8.5.1 Aggregates" (Working Draft N3691 Date: 2013-05-16)

> 7 If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are
>   members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized
>   shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there
>   is no brace-or-equalinitializer, from an empty initializer list
>   (8.5.4).

And below the quote there is an example

```
[ Example: struct S { int a; const char* b; int c; int d = b[a]; }; 
S  ss = { 1, "asdf" };
 initializes ss.a with 1, ss.b with "asdf", ss.c
with the value of an expression of the form int{} (that is, 0), and
ss.d with the value of ss.b[ss.a] (that is, ’s’),
```

So in your example p.y will be initialized by 10.