# Why isn't a struct, empty other than inheriting an aggregate struct, aggregate-initializable?

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, aggregate-initialization, aggregate-type

Consider the following code:

```
struct A {
    int x;
    double y;
};

struct B : public A {};

int main() {
    A a {1, 2.3}; // (*)
    B b {1, 2.3}; // (**)
}
```

Line `(*)` compiles, line `(**)` [doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/3Ccvz5).

Is this because B is not considered an "aggregate type"? If so, why isn't it? If not, what's the reason it can't be constructed this way?

Comment: Before c++17, having any base classes means it's no longer an aggregate. From c++17, `public` base classes are [fine](https://godbolt.org/z/UUZuts). Here's the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0017r1.html) that fixed it.

Comment: @cigien Answer section!

Comment: @ThomasSablik: Yeah, I just wanted to emphasize it.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Fair enough, was going to, but you've got it covered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC 10's default language version is C++14. In C++14 and prior, no aggregate could have any base classes.

The reason? [No good reason.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0017r1.html) So, from C++17, this rule was relaxed; now no aggregate can have no virtual, private, or protected base classes … but others are fine.

**Your code works in C++17. Add `-std=c++17` to your compilation command.**

---

*These rules had [previously been modified for C++14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043750/4386278); be sure to specify which language versions you're interested in when asking a question.*

Comment: What about C++11? Is C++11 like C++14 in that context?

Comment: @einpoklum Bit off topic but **yes** as shown on the linked answer :)

Comment: I would not have guessed something like this would change so recently, when it involves no new language features - which is why I didn't mention the standard version.

Comment: @einpoklum Best not to guess but instead always give version numbers up front to avoid to-and-fro :)

Comment: Also for stuff like this I recommend trying it out on the various language versions; you'd quickly have noticed that this works since C++17, and would then have been able to research the context of that change without any further assistance. In fact, that's how I answered this question: notice that it only took four minutes. :)

Comment: Again, cognitive dissonance prevented me from considering this, but yes, you're right.

Comment: @einpoklum Next time, gadget :D